# Send data from Rest API To kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

I have just started learning Kafka and I am trying to build a prototype to have a producer which is a REST API and send the data to Kafka consumer. I went through quite a lot of documentation to figure out some particular procedure.

I wasn't able to understand if there is a single connector that I could just use just like the fileconnector or the JDBC connectors provided for Apache Kafka. Should I be writing a custom connector for this ?

I am pretty much confused on where to start. I am particularly looking for some structured documentation or idea on how to get this done.

Comment: So you're trying to rebuild the kafka REST Proxy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about the functionality that already exists in the [REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/index.html). This provides a REST API for producing data into Kafka, or consuming data from Kafka.

---

*Edit*: From your comment I understand your question to be different. If you want to pull data from a REST endpoint into Kafka you can use Kafka Connect and the [kafka-connect-rest](https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest) plugin. There's an example of it in use [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-wrangling-apache-kafka-ksql/).

Comment: Does Rest Proxy help me to connect to my Rest API and pull the data to Kafka ? I have already went through both rest proxy and kafka-connect-rest, but I wasn't clear how it was able to pull data from a Rest API.

Comment: rest proxy seems to be a confluent product. needs licese you have to buy ?

Comment: @catch22 it's licensed under the Confluent Community Licence. You can see more at the Github repo https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to write a connector (besides, it's not possible with [python](/questions/tagged/python) to write a Kafka Connector plugin). One already exists for HTTP.

https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest